# Debian to Windows 10 samba share

Tags: samba

*This user can't sign in because this account is currently disabled*

That's the error I get whenever I try to access a samba share hosted on a Debian box from my Windows 10 domain PC.

If I make the share public then I can access it no problem, but it shouldn't be public. As soon as I try and apply any access restrictions it always fails to log in. I've tried countless configs as suggested on various sites I've stumbled across, reset the samba password many times, and generally pulled my hair out for a few hours now. And this is the second time, I first tried this a few months ago but gave up and left it public.

What I want is simple, linux side authentication, so if I have a user called bob with samba password bobs_password, I want to navigate to the share on my Windows machine, enter bob:bobs_password in the box that pops up, and away we go.

I had a share just like this a few years ago and don't remember it taking more than a couple of minutes to set up ...

My config file as it currently is. How much sense it still makes I don't know, it's been changed a lot over the last few hours:

```
[global]
security = user
dns proxy = no
log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
max log size = 1000
syslog = 0
panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d
server role = standalone server
passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .

[share]
path = /home/bob
browsable =yes
writable = yes
read only = no
create mask = 0777
directory mask = 0777
valid users = bob
guest ok = no

[homes]
comment = Home Directories
browseable = no
read only = yes
create mask = 0700
directory mask = 0700
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: In somes cases, from a windows client in a domain, you must specify the machine in your login if the machine is not in the same domain. `Ex: debian_server\bob`

Comment: Ha, that was it!

Comment: good!  I write my comment in a response, you can mark it as  a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In somes cases, from a windows client in a domain, you must specify the machine in your login if the machine is not in the same domain. 
Ex: `debian_server\bob`

Like that, you force the authentication with the credentials stored in your debian box.